# Java getStacktrace returns the wrong line number

Tags: java

TL;DR: *e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()* does not work as expected.

Given the exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 61; columnNumber: 9; Auf Elementtyp "Test" müssen entweder Attributspezifikationen, ">" oder "/>" folgen.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
```

I want to get the lineNumber and columnNumber of the first line (61 and 9).
I tried

```
e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber();
```

to get the lineNumber of the most recent exception. In this case, however, it returns 257 instead of 61.

I've managed to extract the desired line number by brute force with the following snippet:

```
StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
String str = errors.toString();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*").matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    line = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    pos = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve the desired behavior, and most of all:
Why is not the line number of the most recent exception returned, but another one?

Comment: My understanding was that the array contains the "at" clauses, not the initial. Eg each item is a separate stack frame, the trace for the error. The throwable contains/represents the actual frame that triggered the error, and the trace gives you the frames leading to it. The print method, thus, prints the throwable and then the trace. But maybe that changed since I was working with these things in Java 7...

Comment: It looks to me like you're confusing something, the line number in the `SAXParseException` (61) refers to the line number in the xml you're trying to parse. I'm assuming the 257 is the line in the code where the exception occurs.

Comment: The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) for printStackTrace seems to confirm I'm not wildly off the mark. That first line is straight up the toString on the exception. The subsequent lines ("at...") are the stack trace elements. So yes, as daniu points out, line 257 *is* the line number.

Comment: You can test your stuff out with a NPE, they tend to be much simpler in structure without extra numbers muddling stuff up.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the right line number. It is just not the line number you're looking for.

```
e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber();
```

This will return the line number in the **Java** source code where the exception is thrown. It is not the line number of the XML where parsing failed.

This stacktrace element, and thus its line number, is the first `at` line in your stacktrace:

```
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
```

If you want the line (and column) of the XML, you need to use `e.getLineNumber()` (and `e.getColumnNumber()`), assuming `e` is a reference of type [`SAXParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/org/xml/sax/SAXParseException.html), otherwise you will need to cast first.

When trying to get specific data from an exception, it is always a good to read the API documentation to see if that data is exposed (which it is in the case of `SAXParseException`), before resorting to tools like regular expressions.

As an aside, if you do want or need to extract data from an exception message, I would recommend to use `e.getMessage()` instead of printing the entire stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `lineNumber` and `columnNumber` in the first line relate to a position in the XML you're trying to parse (see [SAXParseException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXParseException.html#SAXParseException(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) constructor)